# JVM performance test suite

Tags: java, performance, jvm, benchmarking

I have just ported [phoneME](https://phoneme.dev.java.net/) to our MIPS platform. I feel it runs not that fast; however, is there any performance test suite I can run against to get some quantitative measurement of the performance? I might need to pick some weak points for optimization. In addition, what are common criterions used to evalute a JVM ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at jbenchmark, while I can't vouch for the quality of their benchmark suite, they have a big set of results from running the benchmark on different mobile handsets which should make it easy for your to compare your engine to other engines on similar hardware.

http://www.jbenchmark.com/

Comment: Looks very promising. I will look into it.

Comment: The standard caveats about artificial benchmarks apply; i.e. the numbers produced *may* bear little relationship to your application's actual performance.